# Does IntelliJ have Spring namespaces wizard?

Tags: eclipse, spring, intellij-idea, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

In Spring Source Toolsuite (Eclipse with some Spring tuning) there is nice wizard to pick namespaces when defining new spring config (see picture):

[image]

I wasn't able to find anything like that in IntelliJ. Does it provide something similar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IntelliJ does it much more simply: add the tag with the namespace and IntelliJ will ask you if you'd like it to add it.  No wizard or plugin needed.

Comment: Fair enough, but I would appreciate somethig as that wizard in the future though.

Comment: You're thinking too much like an Eclipse user.

Comment: @duffymo does it adds `xsd` as well. I tried and it missed it. It can has some trouble for example if you want to add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not having any trouble.  I don't know what your issue is.

Comment: @nazar_art It does. For instance, if you want to use the *context* namespace, just add a configuration like **<context:annotation-config/>** inside the XML and IntelliJ automatically adds the following lines: `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"`

Answer (score 8):

I find this a little bit **counterintuitive** for the those switching from Eclipse alongside with Idea users.
Let's take **context** namespace as example (user want to use property-placeholder but don't remember the name of the element correct and don't want to search the internet for a small configuration. All that he knows it's in the context namespace, and adding the context namespace in Idea seems to be suffice to him and help ).
But in Idea he **must know** the namespace and the element by heart in order to help Idea helping him back with namespace. Hmmmm... not so useful.

So:

```
<context $PROMPT
<context: $PROMPT
```

doesn't work

and

```
<property-p$PROMPT + CTRL-SPACE
```

add util namespace

But:

```
<context:property-placeholder $PROMPT + CTRL-SPACE
```

works

Don't get me wrong, I like the way IntelliJ add the namespace on the fly if you copy&paste from google or elsewhere the correct construction, but it doesn't help the one not knowing the namespace and elements by heart.
Why I will never understand is why Idea help users with auto-completing only the springsource namespaces but not the xsdS.

So if the user invoke the autocomplete at the below $PROMPT location:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context=$PROPMP +CTR-SPACE
```

he will be prompted with only the list of all springsource namespaces. But he will not be helped with the schemalocation for the chosen namespaces.

**If you ask me:**

- The way the Idea add the namespace on the fly is a valuable feature
- but this is not sufice. IMHO IDEA should help users with auto-complete for both the namespaces and their xsdS.

Best regards

Comment: Recently I was told that IntelliJ Idea IntelliJ suggests, through Ctrl+Alt+Space, xml elements from another (not yet referred) xml namespaces.
Ctrl+Alt+Space stands for Class names completion but it is also applicable for xml elements completion. 
So in order to get suggestions for property-placeholder type Ctrl+Alt+Space after <p
See 
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5457733
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/auto-completing-code.html
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/class-name-code-completion.html
for further details about this topic.

Comment: Thanks for answer, there's definitelly point in what you're saying. IDEA lacks both this feature and also STS-like Request Mappings view. That's kinda pity.